# DataRepeater newly added row disappear when i clik on other row inserted earlier for copy data

Tags: c#, windows, datarepeater

I have small WinForms application with one TabControl (two TabPages). Each TabPage contains one DataRepeater control. Functionality both DR controls is the same - one databese table binded to one DR control (via DataSet object which is a DataSource created with VC2010 designer). I use BindingNavogator control to manage data in DataRepeater control. Adding new row in DataRepeater control located in TabPage2 works fine. The trouble is when i try to add new row to DataRepeater control located in tabPage1 - in this case currently added row DISAPPEARS when i click on other row inserted earlier (sometimes I need to copy some data from other cells...). How to repair this state for DR in TabPage1? Have you ever seen that app's behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a bug. I had a little mistake into my MySQL database structure. Inside one of my DB tables I had PrimaryKey column defined among others as 'UNSIGNED'. After removing that property my .NET app works fine. Thanks for your attention...